# How to solve Manifest merger failed?

Tags: android, android-manifest

after I set my target and compile sdk versions to 28, I keep seeing this error:

```
Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
    is also present at [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to <application> element at AndroidManifest.xml:8:5-41:19 to override.
```

Here is the app:gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tawkon.data.lib.indooroutdoor"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.6.4"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.1'
    implementation 'com.splunk.mint:mint:4.2.1'
    implementation 'joda-time:joda-time:2.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
    implementation project(':library')
}
```

I tried adding `tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"` to application tag in the manifest, but it keep showing the error:

```
 Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

What can be done to fix this?

Comment: Did you try adding 
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true  in your gradle.properties file

Comment: Check your layouts thoroughly ..whether some where you are using the old appcompat library widgets instead of android x..

Comment: Try replacing implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01' with implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you used **androidx** then please check your **library** project all dependency is androidx or not..
and change this dependency

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to manifest file. And click on Merged Manifest. There you can find the suggestions just click on replace the error will be solved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please change this dependency `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'` to `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'` hopefully it will be of help to you.

Comment: It was originally com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0 I got the same error, this is why I changed it to implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'

Comment: i have already face this issue after that research on that and got some result. Some dependency not migrate in androidx. so simply for now you use only android support dependency. try to downgrade dependency. Hope this work for you.

Answer (score 0):

follow these steps :-

1. add these two lines in grade.properties

android.useAndroidX=true

android.enableJetifier=true

2. Replace implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'  with 
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
3. sync your projects.
4. After sync project u need to change package name from import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity to import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity in Each activity